# El formato de moneda no funciona

Tags: vb

Tengo una consulta que me retorna una suma y quiero guardarla en un textbox de la siguiente manera.

```
 txtResultado.Text = Format(rows(0).ToString, "Q ##,##0.00")
```

Pero lo que me imprime es esto `Q ##,##0.00` y la consulta me retorna esto 1253548.56.

Comment: La funcion `format` formatea dependiendo del tipo de objeto que le pasas, en este caso es un `string` por lo que no aplica el formateo numerico, tendrias que quitar el `toString`, y dependiendo del tipo de dato que retorna la consulta convertir el valor a decimal con la funcion `cdec()`

Answer (score 1):

**Solución 1**

Puedes convertir el valor a `Double` para que lo interprete la parte numérica en la máscara que definas.

```vb
 txtResultado.Text = Format(CDbl(rows(0).ToString), "Q ##,##0.00")
```

**Solución 2**

Debes utilizar [`String.FormatCurrency`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatcurrency?view=netframework-4.8), no es necesario convertir a número el valor que contiene `rows(0).ToString`.

```vb
Dim numeroDecimales As Integer, incluirDigitoLider As Boolean, usarParentesisNeg As Boolean, usarParentesisNeg As Boolean

' Parámetros opcionales
numeroDecimales = 2
incluirDigitoLider = True
usarParentesisNeg = False
agruparDigitos = True

txtResultado.Text = FormatCurrency(rows(0).ToString, numeroDecimales, incluirDigitoLider, usarParentesisNeg, agruparDigitos)
```

Answer (score 0):

La función format no funciona con un string.

Asi que tuve que volver mi resultado en un valor númerico y castearlo en un Decimal de la siguiente forma.

```
txtResultado.Text = Format(CDec(rows(0).ToString), "Q ##,##0.00")
```

y el resultado fue el deseado

> Q 1,253,548.56

Comment: Con el ```CInt``` pierdes los valores decimales, te recomiendo utilizar ```CDbl``` para conservarlos

Comment: Tienes razón, modificare mi respuesta y mi codigo gracias.